# How do I install wxPython in virtualenv

Tags: python, windows, macos, wxpython, virtualenv

I'm on a Mac OSX Lion machine, and I've downloaded wxPython-src-2.9.3.1.tar.bz2. I then did the following (*note: output messages have been removed*):

```
$ tar -xjf wxPython-src-2.9.3.1.tar.bz2
$ cd wxPython-src-2.9.3.1
$ mkdir bld
$ cd bld
$ source /path/to/myvirtualenv/bin/activate
(myvirtualenv)$ cross_compiling=yes
(myvirtualenv)$ export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6.7
(myvirtualenv)$ set arch_flags="-arch ppc64 "
(myvirtualenv)$ ../configure \
--with-mac --enable-monolithic --enable-threads --enable-unicode \
--enable-debug_flag --enable-debug \
--with-libpng --with-libjpeg --with-libtiff --enable-unicode \
--with-opengl --enable-graphics_ctx --with-odbc --enable-gui \
--with-macosx-sdk=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk --with-macosx-version-min=10.6 \
CFLAGS="$arch_flags" CXXFLAGS="$arch_flags" CPPFLAGS="$arch_flags" LDFLAGS="$arch_flags" OBJCFLAGS="$arch_flags" OBJCXXFLAGS="$arch_flags" --prefix=/path/to/myvirtualenv/
$ (myvirtualenv)make
$ (myvirtualenv)make install
```

After that, I did get this message (*so I guess it succeeded*):

```
...
 ------------------------------------------------------

 The installation of wxWidgets is finished.  On certain
 platforms (e.g. Linux) you'll now have to run ldconfig
 if you installed a shared library and also modify the
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH (or equivalent) environment variable.

 wxWidgets comes with no guarantees and doesn't claim
 to be suitable for any purpose.

 Read the wxWindows Licence on licencing conditions.

 ------------------------------------------------------
```

And returned me to my shell. However, I cannot seem to use it

```
(myvirtualenv)$ python
>>> import wxversion
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named wxversion
```

Any ideas how I can have it installed in my virtualenv?

Comment: what did you put for installdir?

Answer (score 8):

For others, here is what worked for me:

On Mac OSX, I installed wxpython with Homebrew using:

```
brew install wxpython
```

Change into your virtualenv site-packages directory:

```
cd /venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

then link the wx.pth

```
ln -s /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx.pth wx.pth
```

and then link the wx-3.0-osx_cocoa directory:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa wx-3.0-osx_cocoa
```

Comment: I was able to install wxpython with brew, but the /venv folder does not exist?

Answer (score 3):

after reading through all the above articles, this is the real key:

you need to point your VE at the main python installation.

On my system its:

`% ln  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wxredirect.pth ./default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wxredirect.pth`

Comment: I think that in this commant, "default" is the name of your VE env, right?    That's not _totally_ obvious :)

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, you can use the same approach that [cweston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37966/cweston) outlined for OS X, translated to calls to `mklink`. I had success creating a virtualenv for an old Python 2.7 / WxPython 2.8 based app by doing the following:

Install WxPython using the installer.

Find the site-packages directory where WxPython was installed. For me,

`C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`

Open a shell and change to the site-packages directory inside the virtualenv to which you want to add WxPython, say it's called `WxApp`:

```
cmd
cd C:\Virtualenvs\WxApp\Lib\site-packages
```

Then create links: hard links for wx.pth and wxversion.py, and a junction for the directory containing the WxPython installation (mine was `wx-2.8-msw-unicode`):

```
mklink /h wx.pth C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx.pth
mklink /h wxversion.py C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wxversion.py
mklink /j wx-2.8-msw-unicode C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\
```

Now I have access to the `wx` module:

```
C:\> C:\VirtualEnvs\WxApp\scripts\activate.bat
(WxApp) C:\>python
ActivePython 2.7.2.5 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 24 2011, 12:21:10) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
>>> wx.version()
'2.8.12.1 (msw-unicode)'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little script that fixes this for my projects. Thought it might be nice to share.

I have the following setup:

- python and wxpython installed through home-brew
- using virtualenvwrapper to manage virtual environments

After starting a new project with mkproject, I run the following script to fix this issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo This script fixes issues with wxpython and virtualenv on mac os. >&2
echo It needs to be run inside a virtualenv created with virtualenvwrapper. >&2
echo It also assumes that wxpython was installed through homebrew. >&2
echo

PYTHON_FULL_VERSION=$(python --version 2>&1 | awk -F ' ' '{ print $2 }')
PYTHON_SHORT_VERSION=$(python -c 'import sys; print "%d.%d" % (sys.version_info[0], sys.version_info[1])')

echo detected python version: "$PYTHON_FULL_VERSION" >&2

[ -d "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ] || { echo "ERROR: First activate the virtualenvironment." >&2; exit 1; }

# PART 1: Add homebrew-installed wx to env's site-packages
HOMEBREW_SITE_PKG="/usr/local/lib/python${PYTHON_SHORT_VERSION}/site-packages"
VENV_SITE_PKG="${VIRTUAL_ENV}/lib/python${PYTHON_SHORT_VERSION}/site-packages"

ln -s "${HOMEBREW_SITE_PKG}/wx.pth" "$VENV_SITE_PKG"
ln -s "${HOMEBREW_SITE_PKG}/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa" "$VENV_SITE_PKG"

# PART 2: At activation of venv we set PYTHONHOME
# NB This needs virtualenvwrapper to work
echo 'export PYTHONHOME="$VIRTUAL_ENV"' >> "${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/postactivate"

# PART 3: link the pythonw executable in the virtualenv
PYTHONW="/usr/local/Cellar/python/${PYTHON_FULL_VERSION}/bin/pythonw"
ln -s "$PYTHONW" "${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/pythonw"

echo "You should now re-activate the environment."
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the cleanest of them all is to have your system python as clean as possible from your development work as possible. The more you add random stuff in there the more it is likely that you will run into some obscure problem.

BUT

Since it is systemwide brew installation that is your easiest choice for wxPython, which for some reason does not seem to have proper python packaging/pip integration. In this case it is going into your systemwide site-packages.

virtualenv supports linking in your system-wide site-packages to your virtualenv in a read-only fashion. Make sure you create the virtualenv with **--system-site-packages** switch. This will make it transparent to the underlying python installation.

I hope this helps people coming accross this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you installed your version of python, you had to require that **CPython** installation be built with `--enable-framework`.
So on your Mac you have to run the following:

```
$ env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework" pyenv install 3.x.x
```